# How to Make <ul> <li> as structured

Tags: html, css

Q.1) My ul li structure is as below

```
<ul class="service">
        <li>
            <ul class="service-sub">
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <ul class="service-sub">
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="service-sub">
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="service-sub">
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="service-sub">
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
                <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I have write below CSS; but not getting exact output.

```
.service{width: 100em;}
.service li {display: inline-block; float: left; width: 10em; padding-left: 10px; margin-left: 10px;}
.service-sub li span:first-child{width:10px;}
```

I need output as below show in image. 
[image]

Q.2) I also want to create the ul li structure as shown in picture. 
[image]

For that i have written the below CSS, but i could not getting how to create that yellow color part.

```
.reseda-autommotive-img li {display:inline-block; border: 2px solid red; background-color: #252324; width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-left: 25px; }
```

Comment: Rather wasting time by casting down vote, do suggest me a solution ... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, i copied your code over and just added this to the css, now it should look like the image you posted:

```css
.service {
  width: 100em;
}
.service li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 12em;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.service-sub li span:first-child {
  width: 10px;
}

img {
  padding-right:15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="service">
  <li>
    <ul class="service-sub">
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <ul class="service-sub">
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="service-sub">
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="service-sub">
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="service-sub">
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Acura Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Chrysler Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Honda Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Jeep Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Mercedes-Benz Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Porche Repair</li>
      <li><span><img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/serimg-1.png" alt="serimg" width="24" height="18" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1139"></span>Subaru Repair</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For the second part of your question I made this (looks bad when you run the snippet, but when you expand it it looks like the image). You will need to add the pictures yourself [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z0dom6ed/)

[image: 2nd Part]

```css
.repair,
.trusted,
.expertise,
.low-cost {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.yellow {
  width: 750px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: -85px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow">

</div>

<div class="repair">

  <div class="red">
    <p>Repair</p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="trusted">

  <div class="red">
    <p>Trusted</p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="expertise">

  <div class="red">
    <p>Expertise</p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="low-cost">

  <div class="red">
    <p>Low Cost</p>
  </div>

</div>
```